# How to update the colum value when we find the same argument in MySQL with php code

Tags: php, mysql

For example:
I want to find if MySQL table have this argument or not

```
$arg1="dog",$arg2="cat"
```

here is MySQL table

```
data1 | data2 | count
------+-------+------
  dog | cat   |
```

after search all the table

if I found table with this value

update the count columns +1

Is any better idea with php or MySQL ?

Is the count columns need to give a initial value?

Comment: Annoying way, there is prolly better but :
SELECT COUNT FROM TABLE WHERE DATA1 = :arg1 AND DATA2 = :arg2

Then UPDATE with what you selected +1 the count column

Comment: You should avoid to have a column named 'COUNT' since it is a SQL function by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for MySQL, you should just run a query like this one :

```
   Update table_name 
   SET    count = count + 1
   WHERE  data1 = 'dog'
   AND    data2 = 'cat'
```

If you want, you could give the count column a default value 0, but its not mandatory.

Upade via php :

```
<?php

  mysql_connect('host','username','password') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_query("THE ABOVE QUERY") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```